# Bad notification for startForeground: java.lang.RuntimeException: invalid channel for service notification

Tags: android, notifications, foreground-service

I am receiving the following crash report from some of my users on devices like the Google Pixel 2, LG Nexus 5X and Nokia 6, 7 or 8 on Android 8+. I am not able to reproduce this crash on an LG V30 with 8.0, Google Pixel with Android 9.0 or emulators with 8.1.

```
Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification for startForeground: java.lang.RuntimeException: invalid channel for service notification: Notification(channel=null pri=-2 contentView=null vibrate=null sound=null smartAlertCount=0x0 defaults=0x0 flags=0x40 color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1768)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6501)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

The only notification for startForeground in my code is a notification that is being displayed during audio playback with android.media.MediaPlayer. I suspect this notification to be the one from the exception, since many users tell me that the MediaPlayer is not working on their phone - but I am not totally sure, since the crash log is not telling exactly where this error occurs.

The Kotlin code for creating this notification looks like this:

```
class MediaPlayerService : Service() {

private var mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer? = null

override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? = null

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
    mediaPlayer?.let { mediaPlayer ->
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {
            mediaPlayer.start()
            showNotification()
        })
        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(URL)
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync()
        } catch (exception: IOException) {
            exception.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
    return Service.START_NOT_STICKY
}

fun showNotification() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as android.app.NotificationManager
        val channel = NotificationChannel(
                "channel_id",
                "Channel",
                android.app.NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW
        ).apply {
            lightColor = Color.GREEN
            enableVibration(true)
            lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC
            setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI, null)
            setShowBadge(false)
        }
        notificationManager?.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }

    NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "channel_id")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
            .setGroup("channel_id")
            .setGroupSummary(false)
            .setColor(Color.GREEN)
            .setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_small)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.drawable.icon_large))
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("Text")
            .setTicker("Text")
            .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Text"))
            .setNumber(1)
            .build()
}
```

I am using Notification Channels for all of my notifications, including the one from above. I am not able to reproduce any problem with these notifications, as they all seem to work as expected for push notifications - and for the most part for the foreground service, too.

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: The error has `channel=null`, i.e., you didn't set a channel on that notification. Please include your code for creating your foreground service notifications and also what triggers creation of your notification channel (i.e., is it directly before you send the notification, etc)

Comment: I do not see where `channelId` is defined or where its value is coming from -- you are referencing it in `NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelId)`. If that is `null`, that would explain your symptoms.

Comment: Thank you for your response! 
I am definitely setting a notification channel with a valid channel id beforehand. I forgot to specify the value of notificationId in the code snippet, since it is an abstraction of the original code. I will edit that. 
The channels are created on the application's onCreate(). Additionally I am ensuring that the corresponding notification channel exists, before showing a notification, and otherwise create it again.

Answer (score 0):

'mysun' had an observation that reduced the complaints for my foreground service:

- The system can not find the specified resources
- This is generally due to `setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon_small)`, which is not yet ready for some circumstances (such as when you start a restart system to send a notification), resulting in an App exception.
- Instead, get the application icon from ApplicationInfo; e.g. `setSmallIcon(context.getApplicationInfo().icon)`

see mysun's [fatalerrors.org post here](https://www.fatalerrors.org/a/bad-notification-posted-from-package-com.notify-couldn-t-create-icon.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, it turned out that my context was null, then I passed the context from the .MyApp main class

```
 PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getActivity
                     (context, 222, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
```

everything worked.

Just try to find out what value your context has, maybe you have null too